# Creating twig files for the a view

Tags: theming

Hi there I'm new to Drupal. I have made a test project, where I've made a custom content-type called 'persons' it has a couple of values. And I made it able to custom style it by making a twig file called 'node--persons.html.twig'. Now I have built a listing view, where I loop through all the 'persons'. It's called 'People view' But I can't get it to work to make a working twig file that is able to properly style every person item in a loop. I've already tried making twig files like views_view--people_view.html.twig etc. But nothing actually seemed to work. I'm very confused about all this stuff and also whenever I need to use a machine_name or so. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend manipulating twig as the ultimate last resort. Drupal provides some core and third-party modules that allow you to manipulate how an entity is rendered:

- [Layout Builder](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/layout-builder) allows you to manipulate an entity's display with layouts.

  - This allows you to create layouts, and use layouts to position fields and blocks on the page.
- Drupal has a very predictable field structure (wrapper, label, value).
- The [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) module allows you to manipulate field markup, add classes, etc.
- Views, just like fields, also has a very predictable markup structure.
- Views also has a built-in way to change field markup, add classes.

I would exhaust those options first before resorting to twig, as those options allow you to manipulate the appearance of an entity without hardcoding everything into a twig file.

As for Views, it has *two* ways of rendering an entity. You either go the *fields* route where you render individual fields, or you surrender rendering to the entity where the the entity Displays are rendered instead of fields.

Drupal 8+ also has a bug where theme suggestions for various parts of the view are not printed in HTML comments. You can find these [suggestions here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x). For convenience, here are some of the options:

```
views-view--foobar--page.html.twig
views-view--page.html.twig
views-view--foobar.html.twig
views-view.html.twig

views-view-unformatted--foobar--page.html.twig
views-view-unformatted--page.html.twig
views-view-unformatted--foobar.html.twig
views-view-unformatted.html.twig

views-view-fields--foobar--page.html.twig
views-view-fields--page.html.twig
views-view-fields--foobar.html.twig
views-view-fields.html.twig
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working by using the right template files (I copied them from a core theme). And added some random html to see if it got printed on the right place. And it works great! Also another thing. I'm building a module that renders pages on custom routes. But does drupal provide a way in controllers to pass data from one page to another and back?